# How to view default android simple_spinner_dropdown_item style

Tags: android, styles, spinner, default

Often i like default android style defined for some widget.

Often i like to just slightly modify this default style, not create my own style from a scratch.

Now, i use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` as dropDownViewResource on my spinner adapter - like this:

`adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

I can open this layout xml file and copy its content to modify it. But the most important part of that xml file is attribute style, it looks like this: `style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"`

Now, my question is: how do i find/view/copy this style `spinnerDropDownItemStyle`, so i can for example just change background color.

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here you can find style `spinnerDropDownItemStyle`:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

But, if you looking for change background of Spinner, you'll need to search for 9 patch images:

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

And here a good example:

http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57

Ty

Comment: Since the wording suggests that Spinner backgrounds _need_ to be 9-patch images, for the sake of completeness, I'd like to point out that, of course, any Drawable (including those defined in XML) can be used.

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml use this direct link for simple_spinner_dropdown_item

Comment: page not found for http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html and http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is . you can make a seprate custom layout and put it on your spinner setDropDownResource()

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
```

Now you can easily make a style for your layout

Comment: how exactly is this answering my question? I wasnt asking "how can i set dropdown view resource for my adapter"... read question first thx...